# Flag to Create Missing Directories During fs.promises.writeFile

Tags: node.js, overwrite, flags

As I review these [file system flags](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_file_system_flags), I'm I correct in concluding that there is no flag you can pass to `fs.promises.writeFile` that will automatically create all missing directories leading up to a filename? If not, which flag does this?

I don't like solutions that check for the existence of the folders first before attempting writeFile, because after the folders are created that check happens every time you write to a file in that folder.

In my program, after the folders are created once, it should always be there, so it seems more efficient to only create the folders if there is an exception. However, I'm hoping there is a flag that avoids all this micro-management.

If a flag for auto-creating the folders doesn't exist for writeFile, then I'd like to attempt writeFile first, and then (only if there is an exception) create the folders recursively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fs.promises.writeFile()` does not automatically create the directory structure for you.   That must exist first.

If you want to automatically create the path because you received an error indicative of a path problem, you can use `fs.promises.mkdir()` and pass the recursive flag.

And you could, of course, create your own wrapper function that calls `fs.promises.writeFile()` and if it gets whatever error you get when the path doesn't exist (you'd have to test to see exactly what that error is), then call `fs.promises.mkdir()` and then repeat the `fs.promises.writeFile()`.  It could all be wrapped in your own utility function.